# HTML Parser to extract text out of the body (in java)

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I am working on this project that requires me to carry out some text manipulation out of the text that I obtain from web pages.
Now, the first step towards doing this would be for me to find a parser that would extract the required body text ignoring the redundant information. I am not sure how I would do this, since I am extremely new to programming. I would really appreciate any help I could get.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick one of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+html+parser

Answer (score 3):

I found this html parser very useful. It also provides  a  sample example . http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I am just now doing it using HTMLParser, available at Sourceforge:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlparser/

Seems very easy and straightforward, but since you claim to be new at this, here is an example with source code:
http://kickjava.com/src/org/htmlparser/parserapplications/StringExtractor.java.htm